# Cannot start TFS 2010 Backup Plan Wizard

Tags: backup, tfs-power-tools

We have TFS 2010 and SP1 and TFS Power Tools December 2011 installed. When I try to run Backup Plan Wizard from TFS Admin Console, the wizard window never gets displayed. Admin Console freezes for a bit and than nothing, but when I close the Admin Console a dialog pops asking do I want to close the wizard.

Has anyone had this issue? Is there a way to run the Backup wizard outside TFS Admin Console?

**EDIT:**

Reinstall of Power Tools didn't help and I've also tried with other users (same thing happens). There are no errors reported in event log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if all SharePoint Web Applications Settings are correct. In TFS Administration Console, go to SharePoint Web Applications and for each web app in Settings window click Verify Path.

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfspowertools/thread/6674fe72-2c2e-4892-a3eb-2d75093c73af/) forum post led me to solution to my problem. In my case the issue wasn't with web application URL, but with port for Central Administration URL. I've recently restored TFS and SharePoint and old port number was in these settings. Once the port number was set correctly, the Backup Plan Wizard was able to launch successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There's a start menu shortcut to:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power
>   Tools\Team Foundation Server Backup Plan\TfsConfigPT.exe" restore

If it doesn't start the UI, try repairing the TFS Power Tools installation via the add/remove programs.

Also check the [Known Issues with the Backup/Restore Power Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2010/09/29/known-issues-with-the-backup-restore-power-tool.aspx)

Comment: That runs a Restore Wizard, but I need to run Backup Plan Wizard. I guess I need to pass different parameter, but don't know which one.